# Url redirection with web config

Tags: redirect, web-config

I need redirect only main domain with web config redirect rules, and redirect an specific subdomain, but not redirect any other subdomain:

What I need:

if [www.maindomain.com](http://www.maindomain.com) -> redirect to [www.maindomain.com/index.html](http://www.maindomain.com/index.html)

if [www.maindomain.com/specificSubdomain](http://www.maindomain.com/specificSubdomain) -> redirect to [www.maindomain.com/specificSubdomain/index.html](http://www.maindomain.com/specificSubdomain/index.html)

if [www.maindomain.com/whateverOther](http://www.maindomain.com/whateverOther) -> not redirect, goes to [www.maindomain.com/whateverOther](http://www.maindomain.com/whateverOther)

Actually I have this code, but It not works appropiately:

```
<rule name="redi" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.maindomain\.com/index.html$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.maindomain\.com/specificSubdomain/$" negate="true" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.maindomain\.com" negate="false" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.maindomain\.com/$" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.maindomain.com/index.html" redirectType="Found"/>
        </rule>
```

I have probed different combinations but any works, ideas? Thanks!